# My python code is not working as my expectations

Tags: python

This is my python code (it's not completed still WIP)
You can also refer this [Cricket Game](https://github.com/arnavnagpurkar/Cricket-Game)

```py
import random

overs = 0.0
innings = 1
computer_score = 0
computer_wickets = 0
user_score = 0
user_wickets = 0
user_decision = ''
computer_decision = ''

def toss():
    global toss_result, toss, user_decision, computer_decision
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter your choice (1 for Heads / 2 for Tails): ")
        if user_input == '1':
            user_choice = "heads"
            break
        elif user_input == '2':
            user_choice = "tails"
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input! Please enter '1' for Heads or '2' for Tails.")

    toss_result = random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])
    
    toss = 'user' if toss_result == user_choice else 'computer'

    if toss == 'user':
        global user_decision, computer_decision
        print("You won the toss!")
        while True:
            user_decision = int(input("Choose to bat (1) or bowl (2): "))
            if user_decision == 1:
                user_decision = 'bat'
                print(f"You chosed to {user_decision} first")
                break
            elif user_decision == 2:
                user_decision = 'bowl'
                print(f"You chosed to {user_decision} first")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input! Please choose '1' to bat or '2' to bowl.")
    else:
        print("Computer won the toss!")
        computer_decision = random.choice(['1', '2'])
        computer_decision = 'bat' if computer_decision == '1' else 'bowl'
        print(f"Computer chose to {computer_decision} first.")

def display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings):
    print(f"\nScoreboard: (Inning: {innings})")
    print(f"Your score: {user_score}/{user_wickets}")
    print(f"Computer's score: {computer_score}/{computer_wickets}")
    print(f"Overs bowled: {overs}")

# Condition 1 - user won the toss and choose to bat first
def condition1():
    print("\nBatting time:")
    print("You get 2 overs(12 balls) you need to set a target for the computer.")
    print("If the computer chases the target, the computer wins. If not, you win.")
    print("If both your and computer's score is the same, it's a tie.\n")
    for i in range(2):  # 2 overs
        for j in range(6):  # 6 balls in an over
            if user_wickets == 2:
                break
            overs += 0.1  # Increment the overs by 0.1 at the start of each ball
            print(f"Here comes {int(overs)}.{int((overs - int(overs)) * 10)}")  # Display overs in the desired format
            user_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 1-6 to score: "))
            comp_inp = random.randint(1, 6)
            if user_inp > 6 or user_inp < 0:
                print("Invalid Option selected")
                continue
            else:
                if user_inp == comp_inp:
                    print(f"You are out, {'One more chance' if user_wickets == 1 else 'No more wickets left.'}")
                    user_wickets += 1
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)                        
                else:
                    user_score += user_inp  # Increment user's score
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)
    
    print(f"Your batting over, your final score is\n{display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)}")
    print(f"Computer has a target of {user_score+1} runs!")
    
    print("\nBowling time:")
    for i in range(2):  # 2 overs
        for j in range(6):  # 6 balls in an over
            if computer_score>user_score:
                print("Computer won the match!")
                break
            if computer_wickets == 2:
                break
            overs += 0.1  # Increment the overs by 0.1 at the start of each ball
            print(f"Here comes {int(overs)}.{int((overs - int(overs)) * 10)}")  # Display overs in the desired format
            comp_inp = random.randint(1, 6)
            user_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 1-6 to take wicket: "))
            if user_inp > 6 or user_inp < 0:
                print("Invalid Option selected")
                continue
            else:
                if comp_inp == user_inp:
                    print(f"Computer is out, {'One more chance' if user_wickets == 1 else 'No more wickets left.'}")
                    computer_wickets += 1
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)                        
                else:
                    computer_score += comp_inp  # Increment computer's score
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)

    if user_score == computer_score:
        print("The match is a tie!")
    elif computer_score > user_score:
        print("Computer won the match!")
    else:
        print("Congrats, You won the match!!")

# Condition 2 - user won the toss and choose to bowl first
def condition2():
    pass

# Condition 3 - computer won the toss and choose to bat first
def condition3():
    pass

# Condition 4 - computer won the toss and choose to bowl first
def condition4():
    pass


def main():
    print("Welcome to CRICKET GAME!\n")
    print("Toss time!!\n")
    toss()

    # Condition 1 - user won the toss and choose to bat first
    if toss_result == 'user' and user_decision == 'bat':
        condition1()

    # Condition 2 - user won the toss and choose to bowl first
    if toss_result == 'user' and user_decision == 'bowl':
        condition2()

    # Condition 3 - computer won the toss and choose to bat first
    if toss_result == 'computer' and computer_decision == 'bat':
        condition3()

    # Condition 4 - computer won the toss and choose to bowl first
    if toss_result == 'computer' and computer_decision == 'bowl':
        condition4()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I win the toss and chose to bat, why condition1() is not executing and the results are not on the console?

Can anyone please fix my issue?

I was expecting that condition1() will execute after i win the toss and chose to bat.
But it's not happening tough.

Comment: You're checking `toss_result` in `main`, which is wrong.  `toss_result` is `'heads'` or `'tails'`, not `'user'` or `'computer'`  The variable you want is `toss`, but you would need to make it global.  Actually, all of your globals should be locals and return values, not globals.  Making everything a global is very bad style and leads to bugs like this.

Comment: Thanks.
I asked to chatgpt too but he didn't found this small error.
I just forgot to check my code.

Thanks @TomKarzes

Comment: condition1() function isn't being invoked when you win the toss and opt to bat. I have figured out just about to answer

Answer (score 1):

1. You have 2 variables named `toss` which is breaking the code
2. `toss_result` is `heads` / `tails`, but you're expecting `toss_result == 'user'`
3. Global variables are [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil), you can instead return the results of the toss and use those locally

I modified `toss()` and `main()` so that `condition1` now runs, but throws a further error - I think you'll want to deal with it yourself :)

```
import random

overs = 0.0
innings = 1
computer_score = 0
computer_wickets = 0
user_score = 0
user_wickets = 0
user_decision = ''
computer_decision = ''

def toss():
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter your choice (1 for Heads / 2 for Tails): ")
        if user_input == '1':
            user_choice = "heads"
            break
        elif user_input == '2':
            user_choice = "tails"
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input! Please enter '1' for Heads or '2' for Tails.")

    toss_result = random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])
    
    toss_winner = 'user' if toss_result == user_choice else 'computer'

    if toss_winner == 'user':
        print("You won the toss!")
        while True:
            decision = int(input("Choose to bat (1) or bowl (2): "))
            if decision == 1:
                decision = 'bat'
                print(f"You chosed to {decision} first")
                break
            elif decision == 2:
                decision = 'bowl'
                print(f"You chosed to {decision} first")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input! Please choose '1' to bat or '2' to bowl.")
    else:
        print("Computer won the toss!")
        decision = random.choice(['1', '2'])
        decision = 'bat' if decision == '1' else 'bowl'
        print(f"Computer chose to {decision} first.")
        
    return toss_winner, decision

def display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings):
    print(f"\nScoreboard: (Inning: {innings})")
    print(f"Your score: {user_score}/{user_wickets}")
    print(f"Computer's score: {computer_score}/{computer_wickets}")
    print(f"Overs bowled: {overs}")

# Condition 1 - user won the toss and choose to bat first
def condition1():
    print("\nBatting time:")
    print("You get 2 overs(12 balls) you need to set a target for the computer.")
    print("If the computer chases the target, the computer wins. If not, you win.")
    print("If both your and computer's score is the same, it's a tie.\n")
    for i in range(2):  # 2 overs
        for j in range(6):  # 6 balls in an over
            if user_wickets == 2:
                break
            overs += 0.1  # Increment the overs by 0.1 at the start of each ball
            print(f"Here comes {int(overs)}.{int((overs - int(overs)) * 10)}")  # Display overs in the desired format
            user_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 1-6 to score: "))
            comp_inp = random.randint(1, 6)
            if user_inp > 6 or user_inp < 0:
                print("Invalid Option selected")
                continue
            else:
                if user_inp == comp_inp:
                    print(f"You are out, {'One more chance' if user_wickets == 1 else 'No more wickets left.'}")
                    user_wickets += 1
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)                        
                else:
                    user_score += user_inp  # Increment user's score
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)
    
    print(f"Your batting over, your final score is\n{display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)}")
    print(f"Computer has a target of {user_score+1} runs!")
    
    print("\nBowling time:")
    for i in range(2):  # 2 overs
        for j in range(6):  # 6 balls in an over
            if computer_score>user_score:
                print("Computer won the match!")
                break
            if computer_wickets == 2:
                break
            overs += 0.1  # Increment the overs by 0.1 at the start of each ball
            print(f"Here comes {int(overs)}.{int((overs - int(overs)) * 10)}")  # Display overs in the desired format
            comp_inp = random.randint(1, 6)
            user_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 1-6 to take wicket: "))
            if user_inp > 6 or user_inp < 0:
                print("Invalid Option selected")
                continue
            else:
                if comp_inp == user_inp:
                    print(f"Computer is out, {'One more chance' if user_wickets == 1 else 'No more wickets left.'}")
                    computer_wickets += 1
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)                        
                else:
                    computer_score += comp_inp  # Increment computer's score
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)

    if user_score == computer_score:
        print("The match is a tie!")
    elif computer_score > user_score:
        print("Computer won the match!")
    else:
        print("Congrats, You won the match!!")

# Condition 2 - user won the toss and choose to bowl first
def condition2():
    pass

# Condition 3 - computer won the toss and choose to bat first
def condition3():
    pass

# Condition 4 - computer won the toss and choose to bowl first
def condition4():
    pass


def main():
    print("Welcome to CRICKET GAME!\n")
    print("Toss time!!\n")
    toss_winner, decision = toss()

    # Condition 1 - user won the toss and choose to bat first
    if toss_winner == 'user' and decision == 'bat':
        condition1()

    # Condition 2 - user won the toss and choose to bowl first
    if toss_winner == 'user' and decision == 'bowl':
        condition2()

    # Condition 3 - computer won the toss and choose to bat first
    if toss_winner == 'computer' and decision == 'bat':
        condition3()

    # Condition 4 - computer won the toss and choose to bowl first
    if toss_winner == 'computer' and decision == 'bowl':
        condition4()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've identified a couple of problems in your code. The main issue is that the condition1() function isn't being invoked when you win the toss and opt to bat. This occurs because you're checking the user_decision variable instead of the user_decision function within the main() function. Furthermore, there's a problem with how you're displaying the final scoreboard. I have Updated your code -

```
import random

overs = 0.0
innings = 1
computer_score = 0
computer_wickets = 0
user_score = 0
user_wickets = 0
user_decision = ''
computer_decision = ''

def toss():
    global toss_result, toss, user_decision, computer_decision
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter your choice (1 for Heads / 2 for Tails): ")
        if user_input == '1':
            user_choice = "heads"
            break
        elif user_input == '2':
            user_choice = "tails"
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input! Please enter '1' for Heads or '2' for Tails.")

    toss_result = random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])
    
    toss = 'user' if toss_result == user_choice else 'computer'

    if toss == 'user':
        global user_decision, computer_decision
        print("You won the toss!")
        while True:
            user_decision = int(input("Choose to bat (1) or bowl (2): "))
            if user_decision == 1:
                user_decision = 'bat'
                print(f"You chose to {user_decision} first")
                break
            elif user_decision == 2:
                user_decision = 'bowl'
                print(f"You chose to {user_decision} first")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input! Please choose '1' to bat or '2' to bowl.")
    else:
        print("Computer won the toss!")
        computer_decision = random.choice(['1', '2'])
        computer_decision = 'bat' if computer_decision == '1' else 'bowl'
        print(f"Computer chose to {computer_decision} first.")

def display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings):
    print(f"\nScoreboard: (Inning: {innings})")
    print(f"Your score: {user_score}/{user_wickets}")
    print(f"Computer's score: {computer_score}/{computer_wickets}")
    print(f"Overs bowled: {overs}")

# Condition 1 - user won the toss and choose to bat first
def condition1():
    print("\nBatting time:")
    print("You get 2 overs(12 balls) to set a target for the computer.")
    print("If the computer chases the target, the computer wins. If not, you win.")
    print("If both your and computer's score is the same, it's a tie.\n")
    for i in range(2):  # 2 overs
        for j in range(6):  # 6 balls in an over
            if user_wickets == 2:
                break
            overs += 0.1  # Increment the overs by 0.1 at the start of each ball
            print(f"Here comes {int(overs)}.{int((overs - int(overs)) * 10)}")  # Display overs in the desired format
            user_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 1-6 to score: "))
            comp_inp = random.randint(1, 6)
            if user_inp > 6 or user_inp < 0:
                print("Invalid Option selected")
                continue
            else:
                if user_inp == comp_inp:
                    print(f"You are out, {'One more chance' if user_wickets == 1 else 'No more wickets left.'}")
                    user_wickets += 1
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)                        
                else:
                    user_score += user_inp  # Increment user's score
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)
    
    print(f"Your batting over, your final score is {user_score}/{user_wickets}") # Fixed this line
    print(f"Computer has a target of {user_score+1} runs!")
    
    print("\nBowling time:")
    for i in range(2):  # 2 overs
        for j in range(6):  # 6 balls in an over
            if computer_score > user_score:
                print("Computer won the match!")
                break
            if computer_wickets == 2:
                break
            overs += 0.1  # Increment the overs by 0.1 at the start of each ball
            print(f"Here comes {int(overs)}.{int((overs - int(overs)) * 10)}")  # Display overs in the desired format
            comp_inp = random.randint(1, 6)
            user_inp = int(input("Enter a number between 1-6 to take a wicket: "))
            if user_inp > 6 or user_inp < 0:
                print("Invalid Option selected")
                continue
            else:
                if comp_inp == user_inp:
                    print(f"Computer is out, {'One more chance' if user_wickets == 1 else 'No more wickets left.'}")
                    computer_wickets += 1
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)                        
                else:
                    computer_score += comp_inp  # Increment computer's score
                    display_scoreboard(user_score, user_wickets, overs, computer_score, computer_wickets, innings)

    if user_score == computer_score:
        print("The match is a tie!")
    elif computer_score > user_score:
        print("Computer won the match!")
    else:
        print("Congrats, You won the match!!")

def main():
    print("Welcome to CRICKET GAME!\n")
    print("Toss time!!\n")
    toss()

    # Condition 1 - user won the toss and choose to bat first
    if toss_result == 'user' and user_decision == 'bat':
        condition1()

    # Condition 2 - user won the toss and choose to bowl first
    if toss_result == 'user' and user_decision == 'bowl':
        condition2()

    # Condition 3 - computer won the toss and choose to bat first
    if toss_result == 'computer' and computer_decision == 'bat':
        condition3()

    # Condition 4 - computer won the toss and choose to bowl first
    if toss_result == 'computer' and computer_decision == 'bowl':
        condition4()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```